# Building a recursive function to create a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I *think* what I want is a recursive function, but please let me know if there's another way to achieve what I want to do!  I'm not sure I'm going to explain this very well, so please let me know if you need further clarification.

I've got a function, findSeed() which takes an id and returns an array that contains information about the "seed":

```
function findSeeds($id) {

  global $wpdb;

  $query = "SELECT * FROM seedTable WHERE id = " . $id;

  $seed = $wpdb->get_row($query, ARRAY_A);

  return $seed;

}
```

It returns the following array:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 9
    [name] => Sign
    [seed1] => 4
    [seed2] => 3
)
```

Where seed 1 and seed 2 are the ids of the seeds needed to create it.  I'm looking to make a function that will create a multidimensional array, in the following format, where the first part of the array contains the first "seed", the next contains the two seeds contained in the first, the next contains the two seeds contained in each of those, and so on:

```
Array
(    
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Stripey Wallpaper
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Green Block
            [1] => Aqua Block
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Bricks
            [1] => Grass
            [2] => Bricks
            [3] => Glass Pane
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Rock
            [1] => Grass
            [2] => Dirt
            [3] => Rock
            [4] => Rock
            [5] => Grass
            [6] => Rock
            [7] => Lava
        )

)
```

I'm doing it so far with a (horrible) function, shown here, but the "map" could be anything between 2 and 8 rows, and I'm struggling to see how to turn it into a neat little function that works for anything:

```
function makeMap($id) {

    // First Row

    $rowNum = 1;

    $oneSeed = findSeeds($id);
    $map[$rowNum][] = $oneSeed[name];

    // Second Row

    $rowNum = $rowNum + 1;

    $twoSeed = findSeeds($oneSeed[seed1]);
    $threeSeed = findSeeds($oneSeed[seed2]); 

    $map[$rowNum][] = $twoSeed[name];        
    $map[$rowNum][] = $threeSeed[name];


    // Third Row

    $rowNum = $rowNum + 1;

    $fourSeed = findSeeds($twoSeed[seed1]);
    $fiveSeed = findSeeds($twoSeed[seed2]);
    $sixSeed = findSeeds($threeSeed[seed1]);
    $sevenSeed = findSeeds($threeSeed[seed2]);

    $map[$rowNum][] = $fourSeed[name];        
    $map[$rowNum][] = $fiveSeed[name];        
    $map[$rowNum][] = $sixSeed[name];        
    $map[$rowNum][] = $sevenSeed[name];

    // Fourth Row

    $rowNum = $rowNum + 1;

    $eightSeed = findSeeds($fourSeed[seed1]);
    $nineSeed = findSeeds($fourSeed[seed2]);
    $tenSeed = findSeeds($fiveSeed[seed1]);
    $elevenSeed = findSeeds($fiveSeed[seed2]);
    $twelveSeed = findSeeds($sixSeed[seed1]);
    $thirteenSeed = findSeeds($sixSeed[seed2]);
    $fourteenSeed = findSeeds($sevenSeed[seed1]);
    $fifteenSeed = findSeeds($sevenSeed[seed2]);

    $map[$rowNum][] = $eightSeed[name];        
    $map[$rowNum][] = $nineSeed[name];        
    $map[$rowNum][] = $tenSeed[name];        
    $map[$rowNum][] = $elevenSeed[name];
    $map[$rowNum][] = $twelveSeed[name];        
    $map[$rowNum][] = $thirteenSeed[name];        
    $map[$rowNum][] = $fourteenSeed[name];        
    $map[$rowNum][] = $fifteenSeed[name];

    return $map; 

}
```

It should stop when all the "row" nodes are blank, so the following only needs to return the first two "rows":

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Wood Block
         )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Dirt
            [1] => Lava
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
             [0] => 
             [1] => 
             [2] => 
             [3] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
             [0] => 
             [1] => 
             [2] => 
             [3] => 
             [4] => 
             [5] => 
             [6] => 
             [7] => 
        )
)
```

Any tips, hints or solutions would be GREATLY appreciated,

Thank you.

Edit:  Quick note on why I'd like it in the above format - I'm then printing out the results in a table, with the first seed spanning the entire row, then breaking it down with the children underneath, like so:

```
$map = makeMap($_POST['theItem']);

    $colspan = count(end(array_values($map)));      

    echo '<h3>' . $map[row1][0] . '</h3><br/>';

    echo '<table>';

    foreach ($map as $row) {

      echo '<tr>';

        foreach ( $row as $cell) {

          echo '<td colspan="'. $colspan .'"><div class="seed">' . $cell . '</div></td>'; 

        }

      $colspan = $colspan / 2;

      echo '</tr>';

    }

    echo '</table>';
```

Comment: You could probably try changing the format of the array to `id => array(**seeds)`. It seems a little saner and easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks, but ideally I'd like to keep it in this format (I'll add a further explanation on why to the above in a sec!).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$array = array('one', 'two', 'three');

for($i =1; $i<= count($array); $i++){
 for($j=0; $j<$i; $j++){
 $arrymulti[$i][$j]= $array[$j];
 }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arrymulti);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => one
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => one
            [1] => two
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => one
            [1] => two
            [2] => three
        )

)
```

[DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ber-v2q)

Comment: This isn't what she wants.  The structure is supposed to be based on the seed values coming from the database, not just a straight arithmetic progression.  Please re-read the question.

Comment: @leftclickben I knew, its an example that she can work on it to justify it according to her needs. I just provided a simple pattern in two loops.

Comment: Thanks to both of you - I was a little confused at first as it's not an absolute solution, but it will be good practice for me to see if I can can tailor it so that it works for my situation!

Answer (score 1):

You can Use this recursive function That I Wrote It For Class

```
static public $map;
static function seeder($id,$Depth=0){
   $Seed=findSeeds($id);
   if(!$Seed){
        return self::$map;
   }
   self::$map[$Depth][]=$Seed['name'];
   self::seeder($Seed['seed1'],$Depth+1);
   self::seeder($Seed['seed2'],$Depth+1);
   if($Depth==0){
       foreach(self::$map as $k=>$v){
          $Flag=true;
          foreach($v as $key=>$Value){
              if($Value!="")$Flag=false;
          }
          if($Flag){
              for($i=$k;$i<=count(self::$map);$i++){
                  @unset(self::$map[$i]);
              }
              break;
          }
       }  
   }
   return self::$map;
}
```

Sample

```
print_r(seeder($ID));
```

The output Is similar of Your sample

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it's almost perfect, however there can be a situation where one of the rows can contain blank rows (these need to be preserved), so it should only exit if the entire row is blank...  If that makes sense?  Sooo close, I'll play with the code to see if I can get it working!

Comment: @ElisabethSadler Hello I Make a little Change On Code That Now I Think Must Work. Test It